# Printing Iterative Pattern in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am new to R and trying to do some practice problems. I have been having a bit of trouble determining how to approach this one:

Write a function or loop that will print the following pattern:

```
[1] 1   
[1] 1 2    
[1] 1 2 3
```

Up to 20, and then back down to 1 again.

I am not sure what the best approach would be. Is this a good instance of a 'for' loop? Is this a matrix that is going to be transposed? I know a little bit of Javascript and am familiar with the 'for' structure there, for example

```
for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
```

But I am not sure how this translates to R. Any ideas? I would appreciate any help! Thank you so much!

Comment: `mapply(seq, c(1:20, 19:1))` or `lapply(c(1:20, 19:1), seq)`

Comment: Or with a `for` loop `for(i in 1:39) if(i < 21) print(1:i) else print(1:(40 - i))`

Comment: You can follow http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r#TOC-For-Loop to more learn about R.